# Parallax with multiple images in the Materialize Library

Tags: image, frontend, parallax, materialize

I'm using parallax from Materialize library but it seems that i can't add an image on the parallax background. How can i do this? I would like to add logos and little images on it.

on the code below, the second image is not displayed.

```
<div class="se-slope parallax-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 se-content parallax">
                    <img src="img/bg-2.jpg" class="parallax-bg">
                    <img src="img/stamp2.png" class="stamp2">
                    <h3 class="white-text">
                        GET OUT THERE
                    </h3>
                    <p class="p-2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        A aperiam aspernatur deserunt dolorem doloremque eos eum id magnam molestias,
                        perspiciatis possimus quo recusandae saepe sit, totam. A labore odio officiis?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue before. You can try adding an image tag inside a div with a class parallax like so:
`<div class="parallax">`
`<img src="imageSrc" alt="backgroundImg"></div>`

Comment: Thanks. It works better. It erased some CSS class but i'll figure it out ;)